# Placeholder for new question is not properly visible

Tags: bug, ios-app

When you start a new question in the iOS app the placeholder for the title field is partly obscured.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 11.2 (Build 15C114)

> [image: placeholder]